# Ajax not showing latest result even after refresh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pdo

I have a basic table (data simplified to attempt to locate problem) which uses jquery .ajax in order to allow data to be inputted, deleted and modified live. This used to work fine however I have recently moved over to PDO instead of mysqli and subsequently converted this code, however it is not working as intended. The fetch_data() function I have created doesn't get the most recent inserted (even after a refresh + it IS in database) meaning the data is incomplete. Wondering if anyone could help.

EDIT 1: Just to be clear, it is only the latest data entry which does not appear, even once the page has been refreshed. That data entry does show however once another new entry has been inputted. (so there is like a buffer of 1 entry before it shows on the table)

index.php

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  function fetch_data()  
  {  
       $.ajax({  
            url:"select.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            success:function(data){  
                 $('#live_data').html(data);  
            }  
       });  
  }  
  fetch_data();  
  $(document).on('click', '#btn_add', function(){  
       var first_name = $('#first_name').text();  
       var last_name = $('#last_name').text();  
       if(first_name == '')  
       {  
            alert("Enter First Name");  
            return false;  
       }  
       if(last_name == '')  
       {  
            alert("Enter Last Name");  
            return false;  
       }  
       $.ajax({  
            url:"insert.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{first_name:first_name, last_name:last_name},  
            dataType:"text",  
            success:function(data)  
            {  
                 alert(data);  
                 fetch_data();  
            }  
       })  
  });  
  function edit_data(id, text, column_name)  
  {  
       $.ajax({  
            url:"edit.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{id:id, text:text, column_name:column_name},  
            dataType:"text",  
            success:function(data){  
                 alert(data);  
            }  
       });  
  }  
  $(document).on('blur', '.first_name', function(){  
       var id = $(this).data("id1");  
       var first_name = $(this).text();  
       edit_data(id, first_name, "first_name");  
  });  
  $(document).on('blur', '.last_name', function(){  
       var id = $(this).data("id2");  
       var last_name = $(this).text();  
       edit_data(id,last_name, "last_name");  
  });  
  $(document).on('click', '.btn_delete', function(){  
       var id=$(this).data("id3");  
       if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?"))  
       {  
            $.ajax({  
                 url:"delete.php",  
                 method:"POST",  
                 data:{id:id},  
                 dataType:"text",  
                 success:function(data){  
                      alert(data);  
                      fetch_data();  
                 }  
            });  
       }  
  });  
 });
```

select.php

```
$dbc = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";port=3306;dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
$dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$output = '';

$dbq = $dbc->prepare('SELECT * FROM tbl_sample ORDER BY id DESC');
$dbq->execute();
$dbq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$output .= '  
<div class="table-responsive">  
    <table class="table table-bordered">  
       <tr>  
         <th width="10%">Id</th>  
         <th width="40%">First Name</th>  
         <th width="40%">Last Name</th>  
         <th width="10%">Delete</th>  
       </tr>';  
if($dbq->fetchColumn() > 0)  
{  
 while($row = $dbq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))  
   {  
    $output .= '  
       <tr>  
         <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>  
         <td class="first_name" data-id1="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["first_name"].'</td>  
         <td class="last_name" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["last_name"].'</td>  
         <td><button type="button" name="delete_btn" data-id3="'.$row["id"].'" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete">x</button></td>  
       </tr>  
';  
  }  
$output .= '  
 <tr>  
  <td></td>  
  <td id="first_name" contenteditable></td>  
  <td id="last_name" contenteditable></td>  
  <td><button type="button" name="btn_add" id="btn_add" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">+</button></td>  
</tr>  
 ';  
}  
else  
{  
$output .= '
 <tr>  
<td colspan="4">Data not Found</td>  
 </tr>';  
 }  
 $output .= '</table>  
 </div>';  
 echo $output;
```

Comment: Try adding `cache: false` to the AJAX request.

Comment: @JonStirling Hi there is 3 separate files for that, insert, delete and edit. However the data is all being modified in the database just fine so i didnt think they would be relevant. Can include them if necissary

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan just tried this, something very strange, it now isnt showing the latest 2 results, even after i removed the cache: false, it now has a buffer of 2.